# MVC 5 (Razor) display database data in View using morris area chart

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, morris.js

I have created MVC 5 (with Razor syntax) in which I would like to display data using morris-area-chart. I would like to use data from the model (i.e. database) which I would pass into my View so that I can use it in morris-area-chart.

Could someone please show me how to construct and replace following morris-area-chart configuration elements data so these elements are set with data obtained from model instead?

```
data: [{ period: '2010-01-01', iphone: 2666, ipad: null, itouch: 2647 },
          { period: '2010-01-02', iphone: 2778, ipad: 2294, itouch: 2441 },
          { period: '2010-01-03', iphone: 4912, ipad: 1969, itouch: 2501 },
          { period: '2010-01-04', iphone: 3767, ipad: 3597, itouch: 5689 }], 
labels: ['iPhone', 'iPad', 'iPod Touch'],
```

If using model and Razor syntax is not possible to achieve my above request then please demonstrate the correct method to display data from model (i.e. database).

View:

```
@model Project.Models.ShowGraphViewModel
....
<div id="morris-area-chart"></div>

@section Styles {
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/morrisStyles")
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/morris")

<script>
    Morris.Area({
    element: 'morris-area-chart',
    data: [{ period: '2010-01-01', iphone: 2666, ipad: null, itouch: 2647 },
           { period: '2010-01-02', iphone: 2778, ipad: 2294, itouch: 2441 },
           { period: '2010-01-03', iphone: 4912, ipad: 1969, itouch: 2501 },
           { period: '2010-01-04', iphone: 3767, ipad: 3597, itouch: 5689 }],
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['iphone', 'ipad', 'itouch'],
    labels: ['iPhone', 'iPad', 'iPod Touch'],
    xLabels: "day",
    pointSize: 2,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true,
    lineColors: ['#87d6c6', '#54cdb4', '#1ab394'],
    lineWidth: 2,
    pointSize: 1,
    });
</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
// GET: ShowGraph
public ActionResult ShowGraph()
{
    // Create model to pass to View
    ShowGraphViewModel graphModel = new ShowGraphViewModel();

    // How to construct following for morris-area-chart?
    // data: ?.....
    // labels = ?....

    return View(graphModel);
}
```

Model:

```
public class ShowGraphViewModel
{
    //What do I put in here?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You view model needs 2 properties `IEnumerable<string> Labels` and `IEnumerable<T> Data` where `T` is a model containing properties for `period`, `iphone` etc. For example

```
public class ChartDataVM
{
    public string period { get; set; }
    public int iphone { get; set; }
    public int? ipad { get; set; }
    public int itouch{ get; set; }
}
public class ShowGraphViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ChartDataVM> Data { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable>string> Labels { get; set; }
}
```

and in the GET method, you might generate it using

```
var model = new ShowGraphViewModel()
{
     Data = new List<ChartDataVM>
     {
         new ChartDataVM(){ period  "2010-01-01", iphone = 2666, itouch = 2647 },
         new ChartDataVM(){ period  "2010-01-02", .... },
         ....
     },
     Labels = new List<string>(){ "iPhone", "iPad", .... }
};
return View(model);
```

Then in the view you can assign the model to a javascript object and assign its properties to your plugin

```
<script>
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))

    Morris.Area({
        element: 'morris-area-chart',
        data: model.Data,
        xkey: 'period',
        ....
        labels: model.Labels,
        ....
```

The view model could also contain other properties needed by the plugin such as `List<string> LineColors`

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly and is so easy to implement too. Thank you :)